# vbscript:Get attribute from classic asp xml object into javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I`m having problem in getting an attribute from a xml object into JavaScript from classic asp. The following is my code:

```
if(len>0){
<%for xx=0 to SNodes.length-1%>//asp code
{
 //Javascript code
var IXmlNode=xmlnewObj.createElement("I");
IXmlNode.setAttribute("a",document.getElementById('a'+xx).value);
IXmlNode.setAttribute("X","<%=SNodes.item(xx).getAttribute("PP")%>");
xmlnewObj.documentElement.appendChild(IXmlNode); 
<% next %>//asp code
}
}
```

Here `SNodes` has xml like:

```
<tag><tag1 a="iii" PP="asdasdf"/><tag1 a="aaa" PP="asdasdf"></tag>
```

Only this line is troubling me:

```
IXmlNode.setAttribute("X","<%=SNodes.item(xx).getAttribute("PP")%>");
```

What is wrong with this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of javascript are you trying to output in the first place? As it stand now you'll get something like this which would never work:

```
if (len > 0) {
    {
        var IXmlNode = xmlnewObj.createElement("I");
            IXmlNode.setAttribute("a", document.getElementById('a' + xx).value);
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("X", "PP");
        xmlnewObj.documentElement.appendChild(IXmlNode);
    }
    {
        var IXmlNode = xmlnewObj.createElement("I");
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("a", document.getElementById('a' + xx).value);
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("X", "PP2");
        xmlnewObj.documentElement.appendChild(IXmlNode);
    }
}
```

It could work like this, but I still doubt that's what you need:

```
if (len > 0) {
    (function() {
        var IXmlNode = xmlnewObj.createElement("I");
            IXmlNode.setAttribute("a", document.getElementById('a' + xx).value);
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("X", "asdasdf");
        xmlnewObj.documentElement.appendChild(IXmlNode);
    })();
    (function() {
        var IXmlNode = xmlnewObj.createElement("I");
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("a", document.getElementById('a' + xx).value);
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("X","asdasdf");
        xmlnewObj.documentElement.appendChild(IXmlNode);
    })();
}
```

You're best option is probably to turn it into a function and pass your asp variables into it:

```
if(len>0){
    <%for xx=0 to SNodes.length-1%>//asp code
    {
        xmlAppender(<%=xx%>, <%=SNodes.item(xx).getAttribute("PP")%>);
    }
    <% next %>
 }

var xmlAppender = function(i, childData) {
        var IXmlNode = xmlnewObj.createElement("I");
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("a", document.getElementById('a' + i).value);
        IXmlNode.setAttribute("X", childData);
        xmlnewObj.documentElement.appendChild(IXmlNode);
    };​
```

Comment: :Thanks for the nice answer,that`s almost the trick,how ''xx'' is not replacing with actual values here?'xx' remains 'xx' only but not wit the value.

Comment: Oh, I see.. should be xmlAppender(<%=xx%>, <%=SNodes.item(xx).getAttribute("PP")%>); I'll edit the answer for that. I hope it works for you.

Comment: :It`s fixed.I just made 'xx' here a javascrpit variable and incremented there.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your quotes in the second parameter to the setAttribute function with backslashes, or use single quotes.